# When does this cron job will execute? 0 3 */29 * *

Tags: cron

I want it to execute every 29 days at 3am, regardless of what day of the month it is.
I suppose if it executes first in 19/sep, the next day will be 18/oct, then 16/nov...

Also, if I run crontab -e today (19/sep), when will be the first execution?

a) 29 days from today

or b) 29/sep?

If the answer is b), is there a way to make it execute immediately or as described in a)?

Comment: bunch of site like https://crontab.guru http://www.cronmaker.com/ http://cron.schlitt.info/ will probably help you

Comment: I came here exactly because crontab.guru says "At 03:00 on every 29th day-of-month.". Because the 29th day of a month is always day 29, so it will execute once a month on day 29.

Comment: if http://cron.schlitt.info/ is correct, the cron job does nothing I'm expecting it to do.

Comment: Consider using a [systemd timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) instead. Unlike cron these can actually be scheduled for periods such as "every 29 days".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do what you want to do with cron alone. If you want to use cron you will need to run your application every day and have it work out if it should continue or exit and wait for the next day.